# Public Key from Transactional Hash of Type 2 EIP-1559

Tags: signature, public-key, ecrecover, ecdsa

Is it possible to derive the public key based solely on information provided from the transaction hash? It must be able to work on newer transactions (type 0x02 transactions EIP-1559).I want to get the public key from a transaction using web3.eth.getTransaction('0xcab61a9889550fe42ffcf59ab615b414a782f23d2039c3d07f5f4bbddcd75206'). Is there any code in Python that does this?   If not, do kindly share why it is not possible :( Thank you!